# SQL Server + Full-Text Search + Unicode and different result sets

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

Full-Text search (`CONTAINS`) on column containing phrases encoded in unicode text.

The objective is for a query containing `ż` to match both `ż` and `z` (ascii representative).

In other words, I need to return same result sets for both Unicode and non-unicode formatted search query.

Please advise on how to achieve this with SQL Server 2008 R2. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full-Text accent sensitivity is a property of the Full-Text catalog.  You can set sensitivity during catalog creation:

[CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ... ACCENT_SENSITITY = OFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189520.aspx)

or modify it after the fact:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG [my_fulltext_catalog] REBUILD WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you kindly for your response.